# Trying to dual boot Ubuntu, Screws up Windows 7 audio

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp

I've been trying to dual boot Ubuntu along side Windows 7 on an HP Pavilion DV6, however, every time I boot into Windows after booting into Ubuntu, I wind up needing to reinstall the audio drivers. The headphone jack doesn't work, and anytime audio plays, it pops loudly before hand.

Info I hadn't included before: When I reinstalled the audio driver and rebooted directly into Windows from through GRUB, I had no audio problems.

Comment: @carnendil This has a reasonable, upvoted answer here, suggesting that our community may be able to address this with Ubuntu-based answers. That would make this on-topic.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer all of your question, but from what you describe it sounds as though your soundcard has options that are being tweaked by ALSA and not changed when you shut down.

Run `alsamixer` in the terminal and ensure that the headphone jack sense is not muted. You can also tweak any other settings as needed from there, and they will stick through reboots - thus solving your issues in Windows.